# Spring client service fetches default profile values from cloud config server instead of active profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-config

Following the [springcloud.io](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-03/spring-cloud-config-server-step-by-step/#gsc.tab=0) document I created a cloud-config server with two property files.

1. microservice-one.properties
2. microservice-one-dev.properties

In my client service application.properties file, I have set the active profile as dev.

```
spring.application.name = microservice-one
spring.profiles.active = dev
spring.config.import = optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888
```

Configuration class.

```
@ConfigurationProperties("microservice-one")
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Application.properties file of config server.

```
   spring.application.name = spring-cloud-config-server
   server.port=8888
   spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri = file:///c:/Users/username/OneDrive/Documents/GitHub/CloudConfigServer
```

microservice-one.properties

```
microservice-one.value = 10
```

microservice-one-dev.properties

```
microservice-one-dev.value = 999
```

config server logs

```
2023-05-30T22:06:21.770-07:00  INFO 16604 --- [           main] c.e.c.c.s.c.CloudConfigServerApplication : Starting CloudConfigServerApplication using Java 17.0.7 with PID 16604
2023-05-30T22:06:21.788-07:00  INFO 16604 --- [           main] c.e.c.c.s.c.CloudConfigServerApplication : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
```

Client service logs

```
2023-05-30T22:07:47.878-07:00  INFO 16732 --- [           main] c.e.d.accessdb.AccessdbApplication       : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2023-05-30T22:07:48.166-07:00  INFO 16732 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2023-05-30T22:07:48.168-07:00  INFO 16732 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=microservice-one, profiles=[default], label=null, version=014e09cb0090a9612ac107733c933e7529a79306, state=null
2023-05-30T22:07:48.202-07:00  INFO 16732 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2023-05-30T22:07:48.211-07:00  INFO 16732 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=microservice-one, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=014e09cb0090a9612ac107733c933e7529a79306, state=null
2023-05-30T22:07:48.247-07:00  INFO 16732 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2023-05-30T22:07:48.288-07:00  INFO 16732 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=microservice-one, profiles=[default], label=null, version=014e09cb0090a9612ac107733c933e7529a79306, state=null
```

why is my client service fetching the config three times ? Why does it switch between dev profile and default profile in each fetch ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logs you provided, it appears that your client service is fetching the config three times because it is making three requests to the config server at `http://localhost:8888`.

The first request is made to fetch the config without specifying any profile, which results in the server returning the config with the default profile. This is indicated by the log line:

```
Located environment: name=microservice-one, profiles=[default], label=null, version=014e09cb0090a9612ac107733c933e7529a79306, state=null
```

The second request is made to fetch the config with the `dev` profile, as specified in your client service's `application.properties` file. This time, the server returns the config with the `dev` profile. This is indicated by the log line:

```
Located environment: name=microservice-one, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=014e09cb0090a9612ac107733c933e7529a79306, state=null
```

The third request is made again without specifying any profile, and the server returns the config with the default profile once more.

It's worth noting that the client service may make multiple requests to the config server during startup to ensure that it has the latest configuration. The number of requests can vary depending on factors such as caching and how the config server responds to requests. In your case, it seems that the client service is fetching the config with different profiles to accommodate different environments.

If you want to avoid multiple requests or ensure that the client service only fetches the config once, you can consider enabling caching on the client side or investigating the behavior of your config server and how it handles requests.

Comment: My problem here is, the client service is returning default profile values when I have set the active profile as "dev". How can I fix this? And can you elaborate more on the "JAVA_HOME not found in your environment." part?

Comment: JAVA_HOME Environment Variable:

The "JAVA_HOME not found in your environment" message indicates that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set or not properly configured.
To fix this issue, determine the location of your Java installation directory (usually the root directory of your JDK installation).
Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable by adding it to your system's environment variables and assigning it the path of your Java installation directory.